# Question about expectation and conditional expectation in pmf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I've been trying this question:

A discrete random variable has probability mass function:

$$
p(x) := \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x\frac{3}{5} & \quad x=0,1,2,\dots \\
             0 & \quad o.w.
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Let $A$ be the event that $X < 2$ and $B$ be the event that $X$ is even (including $0$).

These are the questions. I solved the first three, stuck on the last one.

1. What is the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$?

This is $P(A\mid B) = 0.84$.

2. What is the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$?

This is $P(B\mid A) = 0.71$.

3. Find the expected value of $X$

$$E(X) = 0.67.$$

I got this by computing the summation of $x\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x\frac{3}{5}$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

4. Find the conditional expected value of $X$ given $A^c$.

$E(X | A^c)$

This is where I'm stuck. I got the probabaility of the complement of $A$ to be $4/25$ $(U1 / 1-r)$ but I'm not sure how to use it to get the expected value they want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First observe that you rv is a [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)  $Geo\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)$ counting the failures before the first success.

1)2) and 3) are correct but observe that

3. The expectation is given by $\frac{1-p}{p}=\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{\frac{3}{5}}=\frac{2}{3}$

For 4), without doing a lot of calculation, just remembering that this distribution is memoryless:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X\geq 2]=\mathbb{E}[X]+2=2+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{8}{3}$$

Comment: Ah alright. So it's E(X) + 2 because it starts at 2 positions ahead of where E(X) would start? Since E(X) starts at 0 and this starts at 2?

Comment: @Ben : exactly.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you so much again!! :)